# constexpr compiles on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

I came to know that `constexpr if` is a new feature that we can use in C++17 to do compile time checks using `if` statements. So I've written the following example which prints `else` when I use it in microsoft's vs but gives error in gcc compiler.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4h7odbrcT)

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    if constexpr( constexpr(5) == sizeof(int) )
    {
         std::cout<<"if";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"else";
    }
}
```

Gcc gives error `error: expected primary-expression before 'constexpr'`

Comment: What do you expect `constexpr(5)` to do? I'm surprised MSVC accepts that... `constexpr` isn't a function...

Comment: `constexpr(5)` looks like a function style type cast like `int(5)`, but it is invalid.

Comment: @ChrisMM I think OP is asking "Why is this accepted by MSVC?" and is as surprised as you are (and I'm also astonished this compiles with this compiler). The answer is probably "Well that's a bug. Report it on their tracker", but I'm not familiar enough with this compiler to know if that's some kind of extension that works as intended.

Comment: @Erel I think I also misread the question as "Why does it not compile on gcc?". I am also wondering why OP focuses on `if constexpr` in the text, while the compiler error is for the `constexpr(5)`. Unfortunately there is no question in the whole question.

Comment: Seems like it compiles with `typedef` as well, so maybe it's defaulting to `int` when it gets a specifier with no type name (the normal use of this would be to allow things like `long(5)`).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-use-of-constexpr5/10349254) since msvc's documentation itself prohibits this usage of `constexpr` syntax. This can be seen from the below [constexpr documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>    constexpr literal-type identifier = constant-expression ;
>    constexpr literal-type identifier { constant-expression } ;
>    constexpr literal-type identifier ( params ) ;
>    constexpr ctor ( params ) ;
> ```

As we can see none of the above listed syntax rules is applicable to `constexpr(5)`, which means the program is **ill-formed**.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the [default-int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4431?view=msvc-170) compiler extension for MSVC, that MSVC fails to turn off or warn you about (a compiler bug).

When there is a missing type specifier in a declaration, to be compatible with old C standards, `int` is assumed:

```cpp
main() { return 4; }
// int main() { return 4; }

typedef* p, & r;
// int typedef* p, & r;

static x;
// int static x;
```

So the compiler sees the `constexpr` without a type specifier and just slots in `int`. (You can see that as `constexpr(nullptr)` warns `"cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'int'"`).

This happens with other specifiers:

```cpp
static_assert(typedef(5) == 5);
// static_assert(inline(5) == 5);  // "Syntax error"
static_assert(virtual(5) == 5);
// static_assert(explicit(5) == 5);  // "Syntax error"
struct only_inside_a_class { static_assert(friend(5) == 5); };
static_assert(constexpr(5) == 5);
static_assert(consteval(5) == 5);
static_assert(constinit(5) == 5);
static_assert(register(5) == 5);
static_assert(static(5) == 5);
static_assert(thread_local(5) == 5);
static_assert(extern(5) == 5);
static_assert(mutable(5) == 5);
```